# BIND9 - Open Resolver

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, and bind9.  My Caching only DNS server was actually an open dns resolver, so I am trying to correct this.

I tried to follow [this guide](https://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Resolvers/instructions.html).

named.conf

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
#include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

named.conf.local just contains.

```
    //
    // Do any local configuration here
    //

    // Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
    // organization
    //include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

named.conf.options

```
acl "trusted" {
        127.0.0.1/32;
        X.X.192.0/20;

};

options {
        recursion no;
        additional-from-cache no;
        allow-query { none; };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
};

view "trusted" in {
        match-clients { trusted; };
        allow-query { trusted; };
        recursion yes;
        additional-from-cache yes;
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
};
```

I can restart bind without issue, I can query against bind.  Yet, when i test I am still an open resolver, and when I look at DNS top, all my top queries are coming from IPs outside of the defined ranges.  So I know I have something wrong.

Comment: To start add this `recursion no;` to your options. Then start to read up on ACLs, create an ACL for your local IPs, allow only them to recurse.

Comment: I think he has, if you look at the linked `named.conf.options`.

Comment: Please consolidate all the relevant information into your question so when Pastebin deletes that content this question is still useful to other people.  Thanks.

Comment: Everything should be consolidated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
options {
    directory "/var/named/master";
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; x.y.z.0/19; ...; };
    allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; x.y.z.0/19; ...;  };
```